# c# SqliteConnection set password to database

Tags: sqlite-net

`using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite`;

private readonly string connectionString = @"Data Source=C:\DataBase\FichasPacientes.db";'''

The below connection string get me an error about version not recognized keyword.

`//private readonly string connectionString = @"Data Source=C:\DataBase\DB.db;Version=3;";`

My investigation led to me to this way to set the password, but the function don't exist.

`using (SqliteConnection connect = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))`

`connect.SetPassword("password");`

How can I set the password to the sqlite database?

Answer (score 0):

In `using (SqliteConnection connect = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))`

You need to set the *Password* in your **connectionString**

Example
`Data Source=c:\mydb.db;Version=3;Password=myPassword;`

Comment: As I say on the question the error is 'Keyword not supported: 'version'.'
I need to set the password and then use it